# Android: Street address input with incremental suggestions

Tags: android, widget

I'd like to allow users to type in an address in my Android app. The [Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) provides a nice street address input field to allow the user to enter their home & word addresses. As a street address is being typed, incremental suggestions appear below the text input - an example is shown in the image below. How can I do something similar in my app? Is there a widget that does this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this example code:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/tree/master/PlaceComplete

Hope it helps somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

Well only if you have a way of searching as the user types in the address. Like ***onTextChange*** event of the edit text! you can push query to some server say google maps that provides for the auto-completion on partial query strings.. or if you have a local datastore of previous searches you can provide auto completion on that as well but it'll be very limited.